# ldapsearch failing to show results from custom field

Tags: ldap

Why does this ldapsearch command shows nothing:

`/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ldapmaster.corpintra.net -b ou=people,ou=Mars,ou=Eng,dc=corpintra,dc=net '(ifxAccStatus=unlocked)' uid ifxAccStatus`

The following command returns a bunch of results showing that I have people with the field `ifxAccStatus=unlocked` or `ifxAccStatus=locked`:

`/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ldapmaster.corpintra.net -b ou=people,ou=Mars,ou=Eng,dc=corpintra,dc=net '(ifxAccStatus=*)' uid ifxAccStatus`

How can only list users with ifxAccStatus=unlocked?

Thanks, 
Oz

Comment: Could you please show us the output of second command and the logs on the LDAP server when running the first command?

Comment: @quanta, I would do it gladly, however the first command shows no output.

Comment: Have you tried to filter with different attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an incomplete schema definition -- it's not sufficient to just define your attribute `SYNTAX` (e.g. *directoryString* or *IA5String* OID), this does not define any implicit *matching rules* (comparison operations). You need to do that explicitly with `EQUALITY` and (if appropriate) `SUBSTR`, for example:

```
attributetype ( 1.3.6.1.4.1.xxxxx.1.2.3
    NAME     'ifxAccStatus'
    DESC     'account lock status'
    SYNTAX   1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.26    
    SINGLE-VALUE
    EQUALITY caseIgnoreIA5Match
    SUBSTR   caseIgnoreIA5SubstringsMatch
    USAGE    userApplications
)
```

Similarly, there will be no implicit *ordering rules*, this would need to be specified too if you need to order the results (e.g. *caseIgnoreOrderingMatch*), though this usually doesn't cause as many problems as missing equality and substring operations.